# How Can i Change Href of style.css

Tags: html, css

I have header.php,
In the header.php there is this code

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

But in other pages, for example;  category/product.php the style.css does not appear. Because its on the other folder. If i change href like that:  ../style.css  instead of style.css there is a problem on the index.php.

I want that like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="**HOMEFOLDER**/style.css">
```

Is it possible?
I know i can change easily with javascript but i dont prefer that.

Comment: Add more info, ex: how have you imported the header.php into other files

Comment: I imported like this:  include("../header.php");

Comment: As you write you seems to have access to the php files ... so it is most easily done in php ;-) But no. This cannot be done in CSS. CSS is loaded by html code which is prepared by the php file and cannot change anything in the html code. But just as nice notice for maybe thinking forward: sounds you are working with Wordpress (or another framework/cms). In that case there should be a designated way to add/remove styles.  Maybe you like to prepare some more information so it is easier to help ;-)